# Unable to insert data in databse when trying with $wpdb class

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to create a voting system where user can click to vote! But it will collect their Facebook user id so that one person can't submit more than one vote on a post!
Here is my code which I'm using -

```
$(".vote i").on("click", function() {
    $this = $(this);

    var votePostID = $(this).closest(".scholarship-card").attr("id");
    postID = votePostID;

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            $this.closest(".vote").find("span").html("vote submitted!");
            submitVote(postID);
            FBAPI();
        } else {
            showLoginPopup();
        }
    });

});

function submitVote(post_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "voting.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {postID: post_id, fbID: fb_id},
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log("sending...");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("done...");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.vote);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the PHP standalone file which is being called on ajax request -

```
<?php

    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';

    $postID = $_POST["postID"];
    $fbID = $_POST["fbID"];

    $response = array();


    $response["vote"] = "THIS IS WORKING...";

    $fbID_fetch = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT postID FROM scholarship_votes_uid WHERE uid=$uid");

    $response["fBID_fetch"] = $fbID_fetch;

    if ( $fbID_fetch === null ) {
        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO scholarship_votes_uid(uid, postID) VALUE ($uid, $postID)");
        /*$wpdb->insert('scholarship_votes_uid', 
                        array( 
                            'uid' => $fbID,
                            'postID' => $postID
                        ), 
                        array( 
                            '%d', 
                            '%d' 
        ));*/
        $wpdb->insert('scholarship_votes_count', 
                        array( 
                            'postID' => $postID, 
                            'voteCount' => 0 
                        ), 
                        array( 
                            '%d', 
                            '%d' 
        ));

        $wpdb->query("UPDATE scholarship_votes_count SET voteCount=voteCount+1 WHERE postID=$postID");

    } else {
        $response["error"] = "Already Voted!";
    }


    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Please help me to find the solution. I'm just dying to fix this voting system!

Comment: Where's the error message? please clarify what exactly is the problem you're facing.

Comment: Actullay the error is : when I'm calling the ajax request, it's processing the php file. And the file actually has some codes which should at first check the fb id is existing or not! if the fb id not existed, then it will add the fb id and the post id to a table and also will insert a votecount and post id to another table. But when i'm running the current php code, it's updating the votecount but not adding the fb id and post id to another table which i'm basically using to verify that the fb id already voted or not!

Comment: So let me understand - you've verified the script go into the "if" statement and performs only the last query? the first two aren't executed?

Comment: Maybe you're using `$uid` (which is empty) instead of `$fbID` ?

Comment: Yes! Now I got it...
Thanks Arbels... :)

Comment: Sure, I've added it as an answer, please accept it :) happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$uid` (which is empty) instead of `$fbID`